# How do you remove an element from an array without the index value?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Does anyone know how to remove an element from an array without knowing exactly what spot it is in?

```
var array = ["A", "B", "C"]
```

how would I remove the "A" if there were only a few in the whole array and it contained thousands of strings(Just remove one "A" not all of them)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like this:

```
var array = ["A", "B", "C"]

if let firstIndex = array.indexOf("A") { // Get the first index of "A"
    array.removeAtIndex(firstIndex) // Remove element at that index
}
```

Swift 3:

```
if let firstIndex = array.index(of: "A") {
    array.remove(at: firstIndex)
}
```